# Some images not showing up after deploying to production on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, asset-pipeline

Ok I've Googled around a bunch to try and find this answer and I'm sure it is simple but after trying many of the suggested solutions I'm asking it here.

I'm running a rails 4.0 app and when I deploy (using capistrano) to production some of my images can't be found.

```
Image not found: /assets/venue/hotel/deck.jpg
```

As you can see I have 2 subfolders inside the assets/images folder. This seems to work on development environment but not on production. How can I fix this?

I also have an image referenced in my css that is not showing up.

Comment: Do you have `load 'deploy/assets'` in your Capfile?

Comment: Yes I have load 'deploy/assets' in my capfile

Comment: This might be far fetched but I´m having the same problem, did you manage to solve this?